# Why is the movie titled "Skyfall"?

Tags: title, james-bond, skyfall

Why is the twenty-third James Bond movie titled [Skyfall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1074638/)?

I watched the movie but couldn't find him falling from an airplane or something...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In an [interview](http://www.empireonline.com/features/purvis-and-wade-on-skyfall), Purvis and Wade, authors of the film, claim the title "fell from the sky":

> Neal Purvis: “Unfortunately Rob came up with the title. Not as a
>   title, he came up with the name of the house.”
>
> Robert Wade: “We were looking for a name for this house…”
>
> Purvis: “Like Manderley in (Daphne du Maurier’s) Rebecca.”
>
> Wade: “Exactly. It’s evocative, and you don’t really know what it
>   means. And it was two o’clock in the morning, and the script had to go
>   off, and I typed ‘Skyfall’. So it sort of fell out of the sky,
>   actually. And I never thought that that would end up as the title of
>   the movie. But it obviously struck a chord. But if we’d thought the
>   name of the house would be the name of the film, and the name of the
>   song…”
>
> Purvis: “We’d have talked about it a little bit longer.”
>
> Wade: “And maybe have done a three-syllable house name. Like Manderley
>   – that’s pretty good, actually.”
>
> Purvis: “Yeah. It’s the first two syllable Bond title, actually. Some
>   people find that interesting (laughs).”

Ian Fleming, creator of the James Bond character, never named the Bond ancestral home, but in *You Only Live Twice*, he did write that Bond's parents died in a [mountain climbing accident](http://www.hollywood.com/news/movies/44135764/skyfall-and-the-mystery-behind-james-bond-s-family), so interestingly, they fell from the sky.

Answer (score 24):

[image]

[**Skyfall Lodge**](http://jamesbond.wikia.com/wiki/Skyfall_Lodge) used to be James Bond's home:

> ... **the Bond family resided at *Skyfall Lodge***, though James Bond had not visited his ancestral home since his parents' death. Its only resident ever since has been gamekeeper [Kincade](http://jamesbond.wikia.com/wiki/Kincade).
>
> After they died, Bond's parents were buried in the chapel on the grounds.

Comment: You can see this name on the pillar that represented a gate at the entrance as he drives M to the old homestead - "Skyfall".